# Load to redshift from s3 without redshift credentials

Tags: amazon-redshift

We are loading loading data from S3 to Redshift, but proving redshift username and password on the command line.

Can we do this too role based because this leads to hard coding user name password in code which is a security vulnerability.

```
psql -h $redshift_jdbc_url -U $redshift_db_username -d $redshift_dbname -p $port_number -c "copy $destinationTable$columnList from '$s3fileName' credentials 'aws_iam_role=arn:aws:iam::$account_number:role/$s3role;master_symmetric_key=$master_key' region '$s3region' format as json '$jsonPathFile' timeformat 'auto' GZIP TRUNCATECOLUMNS maxerror $maxError";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Approach 1**:
Generate temporary username / password which has a TTL as part of your script. Use that temporary username / password to connect to DB.

Reference From AWS documentation

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/redshift/get-cluster-credentials.html

**Approach 2**:
Use [AWS Secerets Manager Service](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-secrets-manager-store-distribute-and-rotate-credentials-securely/)

Answer (score 0):

Though this question has nothing to do specifically with Redshift, there could be multiple options to avoid username/password, by mistake checked in to `code repository` like (`cvs`,`git` etc) or getting shared.

Not sure if we do(as stated below) is best practice or not, here is how we do and I think, its safe.

We use the `environment variable` in our case, and those environment variables are outside of source code repository and the shell script code reads usually there at particular `instance`  environment only.

For e.g. if you have shell script that execute the above command, will load the environment file variable like below. example `psql.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Loading environment variable"

. "$HOME/.env"
Your other commands
```

The env file could have variables like below,

```
#!/bin/bash
export REDSHIFT_USER="xxxxxxxxx"
export REDSHIFT_PASSWORD="xxxxxx"
```

There are other options too, but not sure if they work well with Redshift.

- .pgpass file to store the password. refer below link. 
  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-pgpass.html
- "trust authentication" for that specific user, refer below link. 
  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-methods.html#AUTH-TRUST

Hope that answers your question.